# Custom icon on static google maps

Tags: static, icons, maps

I know there is a lot of topic about this but i can't find answer. My custom icon won't display. Here is my link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=640x200&scale=2&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ide-imprimerie.com%2Fdata%2FnewTemplate%2Fpin.png|45.7472473,-0.6246753000000353

But the map is working well as you can see here : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=640x200&scale=2&markers=45.7472473,-0.6246753000000353

also the icon here : http://www.ide-imprimerie.com/data/newTemplate/pin.png

I encoded the URL, tried 32x32/64x64 icon, different icon and I still don't understand why this custom icon won't show up, thank you for reading and helping !

EDIT: Didn't find the issue but shortened url works so thread closed.

Comment: Can you post your code that you did for marker?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will works for you..

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      icon: 'http://www.ide-imprimerie.com/data/newTemplate/pin.png'
      map: map
    });
```

Comment: Nope.. As I said it's a static Gmaps so it's just an url I don't wan to use javascript for this..